# Find the area of quadrilateral RTED

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

In this problem [question 2], I let the radius be $10$.  I was able to find a Pythagorean triple ($\triangle AOE$), so the sides are $10, 8, 6$.

I also know that $\triangle ABD$ has an area of $80$ and $\triangle AOD$ has an area of $40$.

I think I need to find either the area of $\triangle TOE$ or $\triangle TAR$ (which are similar triangles), but for some reason the numbers aren't coming out correctly.

I've labeled side $TE$ as $x$ and $AT$ as $8 - x$, $TR$ as $y$ and $TO$ as $4\sqrt{5} - y$, and set up some proportions, but the two variables are throwing me off.

Am I going in the right direction?  Please help!

[image]

Comment: @Goku , thanks for the edit. But I think you forgot to state the question.

Comment: I took a look at the revisions... https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4594921/revisions Yes, the initial picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/E85Ol.png is showing some more "data", but this is not the good way to sell a good question. Please collect the needed data and present it in a readable order, using at each point only already introduced objects to define new ones. Note that we do not have a **Figure 1**, we have no idea what is the radius in "*I let the radius be $10$*" - to cite a first point where the reader is stuck in the middle. "Texts from pictures" should be typed explicitly.

Comment: Please edit the question to fit the guidelines of the site, see also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question So please avoid text in pictures, instead retype it using mathjax, present the question in a good shape, give references ( so what is "Geometry Word Problems", mention author, year, level, etc) and state one clear question. (*Am I going in a right direction?* is a question, do you really need a Yes or a No only as answer?)

Comment: After further calculations, I think I was able to get the answer.

Let r = 10

Area of ∆AOD = 40 (since the ratio of OE:DE = 3:2, we can say OE = 6, and AE = 8)

From here, my mistake was quite careless.  ∆OET ≈ ∆ORD, OE ≈ OR.  Setting up the proportion 6:4√5 = x:2√5 → x = 3, so the area of ∆OET = 9.  If we do 40 - 20 - 9, that gives us the area of the quadrilateral RTED, which is 11.

Therefore, in terms of S, the area of RTED is (11/80)S